# How to put a cell phone number as exten in AsterNet

Tags: c#, .net, asterisk, asternet

I'm trying to call a cell phone number after i hangup on an internal fixed phone, but it doesn't work, i don't know what is going on... This is the code that i was trying with, but it doesn'work. The fixed phone is called like it should, but the cell phone isn't...

```
var host = "somehost";
Int32 port = someport;
var user = "someuser";
var password = "somepassword";
var manager = new ManagerConnection(host, port, user, password);
manager.Login();

var originateAction = new OriginateAction();
var originateResponse = new ManagerResponse();

originateAction.Channel = "SIP/1040";
originateAction.CallerId = "1040";
originateAction.Context = "from-pstn";
originateAction.Exten = "SIP/CH_CABLECOM_BSL_OUT/somephonenumber";
originateAction.Priority = "1";
originateAction.Timeout = 30000;
originateAction.Async = true;

originateResponse = manager.SendAction(originateAction);
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. What needs to be done is to edit the extensions.conf on asterisk server and add a context. So just add to extensions.conf this->

```
[outbound-context]
exten => _.,1,Dial(SIP/{NAME OF YOUR PROVIDER HERE}/${EXTEN})
```

and originateAction needs to look like this:

```
originateAction.Channel = "SIP/1040";
originateAction.CallerId = "1040";
originateAction.Context = "outbound-context";
originateAction.Exten = "somephonenumber";
originateAction.Priority = "1";
originateAction.Timeout = 30000;
originateAction.Async = true;

originateResponse = manager.SendAction(originateAction);
```

And that's all there is to it

Comment: The extension is intended to be used to indicate the extension in your context where the call should begin. The way you have it set up is a bit of a hack. You can dial a SIP number like this: `originateAction.Channel = "SIP/<trunk/provider name>/sip:+18001231234@domain.com";`